# binary search basic feature

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = [ (123, "cat", "meow", 1.4, 125),
      (245, "dog", "bark", 8.9, 100),
      (573, "cow", "moo", 3.50, 59)]
```

Hello guys, I first time learning how to code. Above is an example of a list.
If I want the user to input anything inside the list, for example, 573.
the system will use a binary search to search for 573 in a list and display out anything related to 573.
 which is (573, "dog", "bark", 8.9, 100).
I really need your help. Thank you very much
If anything I said is unclear, feel free to comment.

Comment: requirement while using binary search is the list/data structure must be sorted. In you case, it is not.

Comment: Sorry, first time using stack overflow, @PSKP if the list is in order? I edited the listing

Comment: I answered your question. if it solves your problem please accept it else whats problem comment.

Comment: How to edit your code that if the user inputs anything like for example "dog", the output will show 1, if the user inputs "meow" the output will show 0. If the user input cow the output will show 2 and 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```py
def binary_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        midval = a[mid][0]
        if midval < x:
            lo = mid+1
        elif midval > x: 
            hi = mid
        else:
            return mid
    return -1

a = [ (123, "cat", "meow", 1.4, 125),
      (245, "dog", "bark", 8.9, 100),
      (573, "cow", "moo", 3.50, 59),
      (873, "cow", "moo", 3.50, 59)]

ans = binary_search(a, 573)
if ans >= 0:
   print(a[ans])
else:
   print("not Found")
```

### Output

It returns position of the element in the list.

```sh
(573, "cow", "moo", 3.50, 59)
```

Comment: How to edit your code that if the user inputs anything like for example "dog", the output will show 1, if the user inputs "meow" the output will show 0. If the user input cow the output will show 2 and 3

Comment: Then you can't use binary search. because requiremnt is that value on which we want to search is sorted. You should use linear search.

Comment: Oh, binary search only can search for the 1 item? which is a specific key is 573?

Comment: Possible to print out "cow", "moo", 3.50, 59 also...? is there a way to do so?

Comment: Output: 573 is at position 2, which is cow, moo, 3.50, 59

Comment: I changed the answer to satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your output should be the tuple? and maybe null if the key wasn't found.

```
def findKey(alist,k):
    n=len(alist)
    if(alist[n//2][0] != k):
        if(n==1):
            pass
        elif(alist[n//2][0] < k):
            return findKey(alist[n//2+1:],k)
        else:
            return findKey(alist[:n//2],k)
    else:
        return alist[n//2]


a = [ (123, "cat", "meow", 1.4, 125),
      (245, "dog", "bark", 8.9, 100),
      (573, "cow", "moo", 3.50, 59),
      (579, "cow", "moo", 3.50, 59)]

print(findKey(a,573))
```